Chats are not appearing on ChatWindowsActivity in Android Studio Java using Firebase
The chats/messages are not appearing on my app's chat windows but when I have checked my firebase database it is showing there properly. Here is the code please look into it.
Chat_Window.java
package com.vortexv.vconnect;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class Chat_Window extends AppCompatActivity {

    String receiver_Img, receiverName, RecieverUID, SenderUID;
    CircleImageView profile;
    TextView receiver_Name;
    CardView send_btn;
    EditText txt_msg;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    public static String senderImg;
    public static String receiverImg;
    String senderRoom, receiverRoom;
    RecyclerView mmessagesAdapter;
    ArrayList<msgModelclass> messageArrayList;
    messagesAdapter messagesAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_window);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        receiverName = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameeee");
        receiver_Img = getIntent().getStringExtra("receiverImg");
        RecieverUID = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");

        messageArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        send_btn = findViewById(R.id.send_btnn);
        txt_msg = findViewById(R.id.txt_msg);
        profile = findViewById(R.id.chat_profileimg);
        receiver_Name = findViewById(R.id.receiver_name);
        mmessagesAdapter = findViewById(R.id.msgAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mmessagesAdapter.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        messagesAdapter = new messagesAdapter(Chat_Window.this, messageArrayList);
        mmessagesAdapter.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);

        Picasso.get().load(receiver_Img).into(profile);
        receiver_Name.setText(receiverName);

        SenderUID = firebaseAuth.getUid();
        senderRoom = SenderUID + RecieverUID;
        receiverRoom = RecieverUID + SenderUID;

        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("user").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists() && snapshot.child("profilepic").exists()) {
                    senderImg = snapshot.child("profilepic").getValue().toString();
                    receiverImg = receiver_Img;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Handle onCancelled
            }
        });

        DatabaseReference chatreference = database.getReference().child("user").child(senderRoom).child("messages");
        chatreference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                messageArrayList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    msgModelclass messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(msgModelclass.class);
                    messageArrayList.add(messages);
                }
                messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                // Handle onCancelled
            }
        });

        send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = txt_msg.getText().toString();
                if (message.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Chat_Window.this, "Enter The Message First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    txt_msg.setText("");
                    Date date = new Date();
                    msgModelclass messages = new msgModelclass(message, SenderUID, date.getTime());
                    DatabaseReference senderRef = database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom).child("messages");
                    DatabaseReference receiverRef = database.getReference().child("chats").child(receiverRoom).child("messages");

                    senderRef.push().setValue(messages).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            receiverRef.push().setValue(messages).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    // Handle onComplete
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

messagesAdapter.java
package com.vortexv.vconnect;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class messagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<msgModelclass> messageAdapterArrayList;
    int ITEM_SEND = 1;
    int ITEM_RECEIVE = 2;

    public messagesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<msgModelclass> messageAdapterArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.messageAdapterArrayList = messageAdapterArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == ITEM_SEND) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sender_layout,parent,false);
            return new senderViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.receiver_layout,parent,false);
            return new receiverViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        msgModelclass messages = messageAdapterArrayList.get(position);
        if (holder.getClass() == senderViewHolder.class) {
            senderViewHolder viewHolder = (senderViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.msgtxt.setText(messages.getMessage());
            Picasso.get().load(Chat_Window.senderImg).into(viewHolder.circleImageView);
        } else {
            receiverViewHolder viewHolder = (receiverViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.msgtxt.setText(messages.getMessage());
            Picasso.get().load(Chat_Window.receiverImg).into(viewHolder.circleImageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageAdapterArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        msgModelclass messages = messageAdapterArrayList.get(position);
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(messages.getSenderId())) {
            return ITEM_SEND;
        } else {
            return ITEM_RECEIVE;
        }
    }

    static class senderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView circleImageView;
        TextView msgtxt;
        senderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilerggg);
            msgtxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msgsendertyp);
        }
    }

    static class receiverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView circleImageView;
        TextView msgtxt;
        receiverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pro);
            msgtxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recivertextset);
        }
    }
}

msgModelClass.java
package com.vortexv.vconnect;

public class msgModelclass {
    String message;
    String senderId;

    public msgModelclass() {
    }

    public msgModelclass(String message, String senderId, long timeStamp) {
        this.message = message;
        this.senderId = senderId;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getSenderId() {
        return senderId;
    }

    public void setSenderId(String senderId) {
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }

    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(long timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    long timeStamp;


}

I have checked the logcat but there is problem in that. Please help me.
If you still facing problem to solve this error, you can tell me what you want to fix this because I am still learning app development so don't know much about it.

If you encounter problems, it's best to create a MCVE when posting a question. You posted almost 500 (five hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read how to ask a question.

@AlexMamo sir now is it okey..?

It's still a lot of code, but more importantly, what troubleshooting have you done? Can you narrow the issue to a specific line of code? Best practice here on SO is to do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. Once you've narrowed that down, include the results in your question and indicate the failing line.

Please edit your question and add the information Jay asked for, and please also respond using @.
